# Meteor mupx ssl configuration

Tags: ssl, meteor

I'm struggling with the Meteor mupx ssl configuration as I can't reconcile it with the files provided by my ssl provider:

```
{

  "ssl": {
  "certificate": "./bundle.crt", // this is a bundle of certificates
  "key": "./private.key", // this is the private key of the certificate
  "port": 443 // 443 is the default value and it's the standard HTTPS port
}
```

According to my provider I have:

- Signed Certificate (PEM Format) (Most web/mail servers)
- Bundle Certificate (Intermediate)
- Root Certificate (CA)

I've tried various combinations of these files without success. How do I build the bundle.crt from these files?

Comment: You can ask your certificate provider to construct the bundle certificate for you. It typically contains Root, Intermediate(s) and  SSL certificate in a particular order. If you know the order, you can simply open up a text editor, and combine these files into one by pasting them in.

Comment: Which server are you deploying the app onto? Reason I ask is that I deployed an app on AWS Ubuntu server. Instead, I copied my bundle.cert and server.key file from my local machine and onto the Ubuntu server and used NginX as a virtual server to configure traffic and load balancing. Just another perspective I know it does not answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference the solution was to concatenate all three in the order given above - but to ensure the begin and end file lines between the files were on separate lines. When you use the cat command they can end up on the same line.